# Web API UrlReferrer is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I've been tasked with logging all the applications that are hitting a web api service. Problem is, Request.UrlReferrer is always null (or has been in all my testing).
We have Symantec endpoint protection on all of our clients and I think that maybe it is stripping the URL referrer from all the requests (or maybe there are no longer any browsers that support it...I've tried Firefox, IE and Chrome).
The only time I could get it to work is if I explicitly set the HttpRequestHeader.Referer, but this defeats the purpose of this activity, which is to find out which applications are using the service.
If we knew all the apps that were hitting it, we wouldn't need to do this exercise. We have over 20,000 employees and the service is an Active Directory lookup, so we *think* it is getting used a lot, but we're not sure.

Comment: how are you hitting your API to expect the referrer to be populated? if you're going directly to an endpoint, it's going to be null

Comment: I'm passing the web service URL and a JSON encoded string with the search options to the UploadString method of a System.Net.WebClient. There are probably some users that are hitting the service via AJAX. That's the thing. We want to find out who is using it, but there isn't a standard way of calling it. So...maybe it can't be done.

Comment: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH101063.html <- Does this help? It's 11 years old, but could still hold some value

Comment: Not sure it's Symantec because, when I explicitly set the referrer in the web client object, the URL referrer is available.

Comment: I need to do something similar. Did you ever get an answer or solution to this?

Comment: Nothing that solved my issue